# How to convert a C# list from {{"a,b,c"},{"c,d,e"}} to {{"a","b","c"},{"c","d","e"}}

Tags: c#

After I read a CSV file by using the code below, I convert it to a list. But then I need to split the sentence, and I don't know how.

```
var parsedResult = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
var records = text.Split("\r\n");
foreach (var record in records)
{
    var fields = record.Split("\r\n");
    var recordItem = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var i = 0;

    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        recordItem.Add(i.ToString(), field);
        i++;
    }

    parsedResult.Add(recordItem);
}
```

How can convert a C# list from {{"a,b,c"},{"c,d,e"}} to {{"a","b","c"},{"c","d","e"}}?

Comment: If you're reading a CSV file I'd suggest using a CSV parser.

Comment: You can use `String.Split()` like you used to get the different lines. For splitting on commas you can use `string.Split(',')`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: `string.Split` is definitely  not the right tool to use for CSVs.  Try `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`  (works in C#.. its an excellent library), or find another proper CSV parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just want your code to produce `{ { "a", "b", "c" }, { "c", "d", "e" } }`, rather that specifically turning `{ { "a,b,c" }, { "c,d,e" } }` into `{ { "a", "b", "c" }, { "c", "d", "e" } }`, I think your code will do what you want if you change the line `var fields = record.Split("\r\n");` to split on `,` instead, i.e. `record.Split(',')`. I don't think splitting by `"\r\n"` there will do much anyway, since all occurrences of `"\r\n"` will have been removed by the earlier split.

As a side note, I'm not sure a `string.Split` overload with a single `string` parameter exists, so you might have to change that to `text.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)`.

Answer (score 0):

so you have a list of lists of one string,
you could use Linq to help you:

```
using System.Linq;


        List<List<string>> BigList = new List<List<string>>(){new List<string>{"a,b,c"}, new List<string>{ "c,d,e" } };
        var result = BigList.Select(l => l[0].Split(',').ToList()).ToList();
```

result is a list of lists of one or more string(s).